# using a dispatch table in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am writing a small program to compute simple derivatives of expressions represented in list form i.e `2x^2` is represented as `(* 2 (exp x 2))` and I have defined the following functions:

```
;; derivative of a constant is 0
(define (diff-constant x E) 0)

;; computes derivative of E with respect to x where E can only be of the form
;; (+ x x ...)
(define (diff-sum x E)
  (cond ((or (not (list? E)) (null? E)) 0)
        ((eq? (car E) x) (+ 1 (diff-sum x (cdr E))))
        (else (diff-sum x (cdr E)))))

;; computes derivative of E with respect to x where E can only be of the form
;; (* x y)
(define (diff-product x E)
  (cond ((and (eq? x (cadr E)) (eq? x (caddr E))) (list '* 2 x))
        ((eq? x (cadr E)) (list (caddr E)))
        ((eq? x (caddr E)) (list (cadr E)))
        (else 0)))

;; computes derivative of E with respect to x where E can only be of the form
;; (expt x y) which is x^y
(define (diff-expt x E)
  (cond ( not (eq? x (cadr E)) 0)
        ((eq? 1 (caddr E)) 0)
        ((eq? 2 (caddr E)) (cadr E))
        (else (list '* (caddr E) (list 'expt x (- (caddr E) 1))))))
```

I also have a dispatch table defined as:

```
;; Dispatch Table of supported operators.
 (define diff-dispatch
   (list (list '+ diff-sum)
         (list '* diff-product)
         (list 'expt diff-expt)
         ))
```

and I am trying to write a function `diff` that takes an equation `E` (in list form) and computes the derivative with respect to `x` and uses the dispatch table to call the pre-defined functions returning the result

here is what I have so far but I can't figure out the rest

```
;; Differentiate expression E with respect to x.
(define (diff x E)
  (cond ((number? E) (diff-constant x E))
        ;; insert code here to handle the other base case - variables
        ...
        (else    ; insert code here to lookup the appropriate function in the
                 ; dispatch table based on the operator in the expression,
                 ; then call that function to differentiate the expression
                     (diff-func x E))))))
```

ex: `(diff 'x '(+ x (* x x)))` should evaluate to `(+ 1 (+ (* 1 (* x)) (* x 1)))` (i.e. 1 + x + x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [SICP book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) there's a whole section explaining in detail how to build a Scheme program for performing symbolic differentiation, take a look at [section §2.3](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.2). In particular, be aware that you're missing one case - what happens if the expression to be derived is a variable? check the link to make sure that you're on the right track.

Now, answering the question: it's simple to implement a dispatcher given the table representation used in the code. Something along these lines will work for obtaining an applying the correct differentiation procedure:

```
((cadr             ; obtain the differentiation procedure
  (assoc           ; look for the differentiation procedure
   (car E)         ; obtain the operator in the expression
   diff-dispatch)) ; dispatch table
 x E)              ; apply the procedure with parameters `x` and `E`
```

Notice that the "trick" for finding the correct procedure to apply lies in the fact that the table is implemented as an association list, and the `assoc` procedure was designed precisely for finding data in such a list. Read more about it in the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28%64%65%66%2E%5F%28%28%6C%69%62%2E%5F%72%61%63%6B%65%74%2F%70%72%69%76%61%74%65%2F%6C%69%73%74%2E%2E%72%6B%74%29%2E%5F%61%73%73%6F%63%29%29).

Answer (score 2):

To add to Óscar López's answer: in a professional-level Racket program, we want dispatch to go as quickly as we can.  If the number of things to test against grows beyond a few items, we probably should use a data structure that supports fast lookup, such as a vector or [hash table](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html).  Data representations can matter: lists are not the best or only data structure we should know.  SICP's bias towards using linked-list representations for everything is laudable.  But sometimes linked lists are not the right structure.

In a hash table-based approach, the set up for the dispatch table stays very similar:

```
;; in professional-level Racket (#lang racket)
(define dispatch-table (hash '+ diff-sum
                             '* diff-product
                             ;; ... etc
                             ))
```

Lookup into the table is a [hash-ref](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._hash-ref%29%29) away.

```
(define op '+)
(hash-ref dispatch-table op)      ;;; => diff-sum
```